# The city of fortune & failure

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> In Unit nine in Xiamen I live,
>   Away from the windows.
>
> Although I'm not edible,
>   I'm quite tasty if followed by Ed and Eddy.
>
> Committed no crime,
>   I will be executed.
>
> You might think i died,
>   and put me in *me in* under the ground.

**What am I?**

> Hint 1: I was happily living until an *elf* comes along and kills me.  Luckily I changed myself and escaped through 10 windows =)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you...

> the [Common Object File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF)?

In Unit nine in Xiamen I live,
Away from the windows.

> **U**nit **n**ine **i**n **X**iamen represents Unix, which is where COFF originated.

Although I'm not edible,
I'm quite tasty if followed by Ed and Eddy.

> "Coffee" (i.e. COFF+"E"+"E"), a tasty beverage.

Committed no crime,
I will be executed.

> Stores code to be "executed" (but not as a criminal would be).

You might think i died,
and put me in *me in* under the ground.

> A "coffin" (COFF + "in") is used to bury dead things.

The title...

> hints at the answer: "The **c**ity **o**f **f**ortune & **f**ailure"

And finally, regarding the hint...

> [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) largely replaced COFF, but variants continue to be used on Windows systems.

Comment: You are on the very right track - The answer is something similar

Comment: "You might think i died"... the format is also largely dead.

Comment: Should be mentioned that @Alex responded when the suggestion was the YUM utility. Gnovice then later edited it to the COFF format. I think this one is it :)

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score 6):

Are you an

> iPhone

In Unit nine in Xiamen I live,

> u - n - i - x unix system

Away from the windows.

> apple, not windows

Although I'm not edible,

> apple, but not edible

I'm quite tasty if followed by Ed and Eddy.

> not sure on this one

Committed no crime,
I will be executed.

> Executing an app on the phone?

You might think i died,
and put me in me in under the ground.

> Plugging your charger in the prongs go under the ground line

Comment: Good attempt!  Although it's not the answer, you do have at least 1 line correct.

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> Raspberry pi

```
In Unit nine in Xiamen I live,
Away from the windows.
```

> U N I X - Raspberry pi is unix based (AND NOT WINDOWS) (CREDIT to Pat)

```
Although I'm not edible,
I'm quite tasty if followed by Ed and Eddy.
```

> Edible? Seems like wordplay on the word Pi (pie) Not sure about the Ed and Eddy reference unless it has to do with Pinkie Pie?

```
Committed no crime,
I will be executed.
```

> C rhyme? Unix is c generated, and this riddle is about UNIX and C

```
You might think i died,
and put me in me in under the ground.
```

> An obvious homage to plugging in the Pi for new life (Boss ME power adapter maybe?)

Comment: Raspberry pi!  This new toy is very capable!  Sadly it is not the answer - You've the same line correct as Pat.  Here's a small hint: while Raspberry Pi is kinda new, the answer is quite the opposite